# How to view unknown HTML tag in QLabel?

Tags: html, c++, qt, qt4

I want to show a text in a QLabel which looks like this:  **<MyText>** 
But  is not displayed. I need to display text with angular brackets.

For example:

Input string:   <b> <MyText> </b>

Output string:  **<MyText>**

I know that to show angular brackets - user can type: <b> &lt ; MyText&gt ; </b> But this variant does not fit.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this variant does not fit'?

Comment: You have a space in your entities `<b> &lt ; MyText&gt ; </b>` should be `<b>&lt; MyText&gt;</b>`

Comment: Try with QString::toHtmlEscaped()

Comment: Or try QString Qt::escape(const QString & plain)  in Qt4
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#escape

Comment: Your input string is not properly encoded HTML, so it has no chance of working. The fix is wherever this broken text is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label->setText("<b>&lt;MyText&gt;</b>");
```

Works fine to me.